# Multiple parent models in one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I can't seem to find any example of this so I wonder if I am doing it completely wrong or over-complicating it.

I have a Contacts model that belongs to an Installation. There are many different contact categories (auto, health, children..) So in the contacts/new form I want to have one form but multiple records can be added to the Contact model with this one form.

For example there is an Auto section with a contact fields, a Health section with a contact fields, ad one submit button. The only thing they have in common is what installation they belong to but I won't know that until they go to fill out the form.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the array syntax for form input, this will enable you to have an array of Contacts nested within your Installation form.

For instance, you might do:

```
<%= form_for @installation do |f| %>
  <% for category in @categories do %>
    # category is 'auto', 'health', 'children', etc.
    <%= fields_for 'installation[#{category}][contacts][]' do |contact_f| %>
      <%= contact_f.text_field :contact_data_field %>
      # more fields here
    <% end %> 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Then in your installation controller you would need to deal with a params hash that looks something like:

`{'installation' => { 'auto' => { 'contacts' => [ # an array of contact data hashes ] }}}`

Check out [understanding-parameter-naming-conventions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#understanding-parameter-naming-conventions) in the rails guide on the form helpers.

ian.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a `nested form` in rails, if you search you will find a lot of resources to help you further. For example, to get you started: check out [this post on asciicasts](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) (the readable version of railscasts.com).